# How to use Image EXIF Autorotate?

Tags: 7, media

I have been trying to use the Image [EXIF Autorotate](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_exif_autorotate) Module. I have installed all the required modules like

- Imagecache Autorotate
- Original image with style

Also changed the image field property

- Apply style to image after upload = Image EXIF Autorotate

Nothing is happening I upload the image and no changes and it just upload the image as it is and if I try to rotate it manually nothing happens.

My requirements are as the image is uploaded the user sees the image and if wants to rotate it by clicking on it to do so.

Comment: Note that this submodule requires the **Exif PHP extension to be enabled**.

Comment: and [Automatically rotate image on upload](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73698/automatically-rotate-image-on-upload)

Answer (score 1):

The Exif Autorotate module

> Automatically rotates any uploaded image file according to the EXIF
>   orientation information.

This EXIF data is embedded into the photo by the camera (and is often lost in compression). It contains the author, aperture settings, shutter speed, camera position and [much more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format).

So if your photo is not created by a camera, or is already in the upright position, or has been compressed or downloaded, nothing will happen.

> My requirements are as the image is uploaded the user sees the image
>   and if wants to rotate it by clicking on it to do so.

EXIF Autorotate does not rotate the photo by clicking on it, it rotates the photo to the position the camera shot it in (landscape or portrait).